# How do i seed a table that has a foreign key, which is specified as an object in the model, but as a guid in the table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

so i have a problem with Entity Framework 6 and its code-first implementation. When creating the two tables, i set up one to have a foreign key that is an id (guid) from the other. I made this by making one of the properties of the table to be of an object type (as seen in the code). When i open the database explorer, the column shows as a string, representing an id (i guess EF figured out on its own about the relation). However, when i try to seed the second table, and provide an instance of the model of the first table to the second's foreign key, i get an error saying "Unable to create a constant value of type 'cq.Models.SurveyTemplate'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.". When i try to add a string (the guid of the parent table), i get an error that the model expects a property of the SurveyTemplate type, not a literal string. I can make the property just be a string in the model, but isn't the idea that i set it to a model, and let EF do its relation? Thanks for your help in advance :)
Also, automatic migrations are set to true

This is the seed method

```cs
protected override void Seed(cq.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {
    SurveyTemplate surveyTemplate = context.SurveyTemplates.Find(
    "d87ab2a8-4eb4-4272-b7e4-afe2f8999b4e");
    context.QuestionTemplates.AddOrUpdate(q => new { 
        q.Text, q.SurveyTemplate 
    }, new QuestionTemplate {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Text = "What is your contact info?",
        Type = "Contact Info",
        SurveyTemplate = surveyTemplate
    });
}
```

This is the SurveyTemplate model

```cs
    public class SurveyTemplate {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is the QuestionTemplate model

```cs
    public class QuestionTemplate {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public SurveyTemplate SurveyTemplate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, for any future people having this problem, I think I found the solution to the problem, being that I am quite new to ASP.NET MVC. When creating the `QuestionTemplate` model, not only do you need to create `public SurveyTemplate SurveyTemplate { get; set; }`, but you also need to specify a `public string SurveyTemplateId { get; set; }`, and place a `[ForeignKey("SurveyTemplateId")]` annotation before the SurveyTemplate property, in order for the framework to understand what you're trying to do when adding or seeding. Here's my seed method and model:

```cs
protected override void Seed(cq.Models.ApplicationDbContext context) {
    SurveyTemplate surveyTemplate = context.SurveyTemplates.Find("d87ab2a8-4eb4-4272-b7e4-afe2f8999b4e");
    if (!context.QuestionTemplates.Any(q => q.Text == questionTemplate.Text && q.SurveyTemplate.Id == questionTemplate.SurveyTemplate.Id)) {
        context.QuestionTemplates.Add(new QuestionTemplate {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            Text = "What is your contact info?",
            Type = "Contact Info",
            SurveyTemplate = surveyTemplate
        });

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

```cs
public class QuestionTemplate {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SurveyTemplateId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SurveyTemplateId")]
    public SurveyTemplate SurveyTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

I hope I helped someone!

Edit: Since apparently AddOrUpdate is quite unreliable, i switched it up, you should see it in the code. Cheers!

Comment: I think you pasted the old seeding code. Shouldn't you have set `SurveyTemplateId`?

Comment: @GertArnold I thought so too, but apparently Entity Framework figures it out on its own, since there's an annotation that leads to the SurveyTemplateId above the SurveyTemplate.

Comment: Yeah, that's quite different now. Anyway, if you know the id there's no need for the database roundtrip to find the `SurveyTemplate`. You can set `SurveyTemplateId` directly.

Comment: @GertArnold thank you, you're right. It works if i set it to `SurveyTemplateId` too, but  will it know it's a foreign key now? After all, in the model it's still only a string.